# How do you display image path in another form after loading an image?

Tags: c#

I want to load an image from form 1 into another form and also show the image path in a label of the second form.

This is my code so far:

```
private void llblOpenSavedImages_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName))
            {
                Open_Saved_Design_Form frm = new Open_Saved_Design_Form(dlg.FileName);
                frm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the second form:

```
public Open_Saved_Design_Form(string imagePath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    private void Open_Saved_Design_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbxArt.ImageLocation = _imagePath;
    }
```

Comment: Well, do you see the loaded image?

Comment: Yes all I need now is to show the path in a label (where it came from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you have a label named Label1 in your second form, you just need to add

```
public Open_Saved_Design_Form(string imagePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _imagePath = imagePath;
}

private void Open_Saved_Design_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pbxArt.ImageLocation = _imagePath;
    Label1.Text = _imagePath;
}
```

Of course you need to be sure that the label is visible and not covered by the PictureBox.
For example you could set the Dock property for the Label1 to Bottom and then set the Dock property for the PictureBox to Fill

Comment: Thanks. That was pretty simple.